# Minimizing a function using PyTorch Optimizer - Return values are all the same

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I'm trying to minimize a function in order to better understand the optimizer process. As an example I used the Eggholder-Function ([https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/egg.html](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Essurjano/egg.html)) which is 2d. My goal is to get the values of my parameters (x and y) after every optimizer iteration so that i can visualize it afterwards.

Using Pytorch I wrote the following code:

```
def eggholder_function(x):
    return -(x[1] + 47) * torch.sin(torch.sqrt(torch.abs(x[1] + x[0]/2 + 47))) - x[0]*torch.sin(torch.sqrt(torch.abs(x[0]-(x[1]+47))))

def minimize(function, initial_parameters):
    list_params = []
    params = initial_parameters
    params.requires_grad_()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([params], lr=0.1)

    for i in range(5):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = function(params)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        list_params.append(params)
        


    return params, list_params

starting_point = torch.tensor([-30.,-10.])
minimized_params, list_of_params = minimize(eggholder_function, starting_point)
```

The output is as follows:

`minimized_params: tensor([-29.4984, -10.5021], requires_grad=True)`

and

```
list of params:


[tensor([-29.4984, -10.5021], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([-29.4984, -10.5021], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([-29.4984, -10.5021], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([-29.4984, -10.5021], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([-29.4984, -10.5021], requires_grad=True)]
```

While I understand that the minimized_params is infact the optimized minimum, why does list_of_params show the same values for every iteration?

Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they all refer to the same object. You can check it by:

```py
id(list_of_params[0]), id(list_of_params[1])
```

You can clone the params to avoid that:

```py
import torch
def eggholder_function(x):
    return -(x[1] + 47) * torch.sin(torch.sqrt(torch.abs(x[1] + x[0]/2 + 47))) - x[0]*torch.sin(torch.sqrt(torch.abs(x[0]-(x[1]+47))))

def minimize(function, initial_parameters):
    list_params = []
    params = initial_parameters
    params.requires_grad_()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([params], lr=0.1)

    for i in range(5):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = function(params)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        list_params.append(params.detach().clone()) #here
        
    return params, list_params

starting_point = torch.tensor([-30.,-10.])
minimized_params, list_of_params = minimize(eggholder_function, starting_point)
```

```bash
#list_params
[tensor([-29.9000, -10.1000]),
 tensor([-29.7999, -10.2001]),
 tensor([-29.6996, -10.3005]),
 tensor([-29.5992, -10.4011]),
 tensor([-29.4984, -10.5021])]
```

Comment: We made the same answer at the same time :) I just used `deepcopy` instead

Comment: Haha. Either works!

Answer (score 2):

The tensor is changed while you optimize, as such of all its shallow copies in the list are changed, in order to fix your problem you should use `deepcopy`, as deepcopies do not change when the original is changed:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def eggholder_function(x):
    return -(x[1] + 47) * torch.sin(torch.sqrt(torch.abs(x[1] + x[0]/2 + 47))) - x[0]*torch.sin(torch.sqrt(torch.abs(x[0]-(x[1]+47))))

def minimize(function, initial_parameters):
    list_params = []
    params = initial_parameters
    params.requires_grad_()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([params], lr=0.1)

    for i in range(5):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = function(params)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        list_params.append(deepcopy(params))
        


    return params, list_params

starting_point = torch.tensor([-30.,-10.])
minimized_params, list_of_params = minimize(eggholder_function, starting_point)
print(minimized_params, list_of_params)
```

The outputs now are in fact different from one another and only the last one is equal to the final result:

```
(tensor([-29.9000, -10.1000], requires_grad=True),
[tensor([-29.9000, -10.1000]),
 tensor([-29.7999, -10.2001]),
 tensor([-29.6996, -10.3005]),
 tensor([-29.5992, -10.4011]),
 tensor([-29.4984, -10.5021])]
```

Many problems can derive from using shallow copies, when writing the first version of my code I use `deepcopy` as much as possible, then remove it when (if) space optimization is needed.

Comment: @telias thanks to you for the interesting question, remember to also upvote the other answer that is also correct!

Comment: (upvoting means clicking the up-arrow, accepting means clicking the checkmark, only one answer can be accepted but all can be upvoted)

Comment: Unfortunately upvoting is only available at 15+ rep, so i'm unable to do so :( sorry!

Comment: @telias No problem, you will soon gain reputation as you ask clear and interesting questions. Have a nice day :)